# How do I edit the command to compile and run java file in vscode terminal?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Whenever I run a java program, both class name and filename have to be same, because the command to compile and run java in vscode terminal is:

```
cd "c:\Users\user\Desktop\Java\" ; if ($?) { javac MyProgram.java } ; if ($?) { java MyProgram }
```

and when my class name is different from filename I have to edit the command to `...; if ($?) { java ActualClassname }` in terminal every time I run the code.

So how do I change this command for running and compiling java program in vscode?

I just have to change it a little bit from:

```
cd "c:\Users\user\Desktop\Java\" ; if ($?) { javac MyProgram.java } ; if ($?) { java MyProgram }
```

to:

```
cd "c:\Users\user\Desktop\Java\" ; if ($?) { javac MyProgram.java } ; if ($?) { java MyProgram.java }
```

Adding `.java` in the end seems to solve my problem whenever I have different class name from filename.

Reason for asking this is some names for class were giving me errors
for example:

```
//reverse-string.java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class reverse-string //error:"invalid modifiers"
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str, rev="";
        char ch;
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a String:");
        str = in.next();
        System.out.println("String = "+str);
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            ch = str.charAt(i);
            rev = ch + rev;
        }
        System.out.println("Reverse String = "+rev);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

So I used different names for class and file that's why had to remove `public` from class:

```
//reverse-string.java
import java.util.Scanner;
class ReverseString
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str, rev="";
        char ch;
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a String:");
        str = in.next();
        System.out.println("String = "+str);
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            ch = str.charAt(i);
            rev = ch + rev;
        }
        System.out.println("Reverse String = "+rev);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

and that worked both in vscode and command line using `javac reverse-string.java` and `java ReverseString`

After searching in the internet (chatgpt) I found out that changing the `task.json` in `.vscode` directory would change the command that is required to run the program. But I don't know how do I change and even how do I open this `task.json` only for Java? It is very confusing.

Comment: Don't mess with this. Java requires that `public class Foo` is defined in `Foo.java`. Don't try to get around that unless you have a very good reason and know what you are doing.

Comment: @Robert I know that's why I defined my class without `public` so that i can use different class name and filename.

Comment: Don't work against the framework. Why do you want to have different names in the first place? You're making it hard for yourself and everyone using your code. This sounds a lot like an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @Robert Well one of reasons was that I couldn't use some names both for file and class and gave errors like 'Invalid Modifiers' and 'Syntax error' etc..

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and give an example of a class that causes the "invalid modifiers" error?

Comment: `reverse-string` is not a valid class name. This has nothing to do with VS Code. It just enforces the rules that Java defines. I recommend that you read about valid names in Java to understand this better.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes I know but it is a valid filename and that's why I was using different names for filename and class name without using `public` . I just wanted to know if there's a way to run code that has class name different from filename .

Comment: @SunnySoren No, you must keep the class name and file name the same. This is a rule from Java and VS Code is just helping you follow the rules.

Comment: @SunnySoren I recommend trying to compile and run your code from the command line without VS Code. You will still encounter errors if you try to make the class name and file name different. This shows that the problem is your code not following the rules defined by Java rather than a problem with VS Code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I see. I was just wondering as compiling and running can be done separately in cmd maybe there is a way in vscode(without manually entering command in terminal) . I see that using different names for class name and filename is just bad practice and that's what vscode is trying to tell.

Comment: As I said, try it from the command line. If you can't do what you want there, then VS Code can't do it, either.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yeah I asked a question here because it worked in cmd and also in vscode(just had to rewrite command in vscode terminal)

Comment: Note that ChatGPT is not the same as "searched the internet". Please do not confuse the two. ChatGPT is a great tool when used properly, but it has the tendency to be flat out wrong at times. Use it with a critical eye.

Comment: Also, when I create a file named `reverse-string.java` with a public class named `RverseString`, I get an error. What OS and version of Java did you use?  I'm on macos... not sure which Java version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using **Code Runner** to run the script. Add this setting

```json
    "code-runner.customCommand": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileName",
```

Then select `RUn Custom Command` in the command panel or use the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to execute the script using the command you defined.

[image]

Or you can also modify the execution command of the java language in the `code-runner.executorMap` setting:

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/blob/master/README.md#configuration

Answer (score 1):

Java requires that the .java file name matches the name of the public class defined in that file. VS Code is simply helping you follow this rule. You shouldn't try to get around it.

The real problem here is that `reverse-string` is not a valid class name because `-` is not allowed in any identifier in Java. Instead, you should name the class `ReverseString` and the file as `ReverseString.java`. While the capital first letter is not strictly required by Java, it is a common convention to differentiate class names easily from other names, such as methods and variables.

Alternatively, Java won't allow you to name the file `reverse-string.java` with a class named `ReverseString`. I recommend using the command line directly with something like `javac reverse-string.java` to try it. Even if this works, running `java ReverseString` won't work.

Comment: @sunny To add to this: follow conventions like for naming, or you will confuse people who try to work with you and your code. Python can take this to extremes, but the idea is the same: make your code easy to read and work with. Trying to force different file names is the opposite of this. You are wasting a lot of time and effort on something you really shouldn't do in the first place.

Comment: This is a bit confusing as both `javac reverse-string.java` and `java ReverseString` worked for me after removing `public` from class.

Comment: @SunnySoren You will have to post the code that you used that "worked" along with the exact commands because `javac reverse-string.java` doesn't work for me. Be sure you don't have any left-over .java or .class files from previous attempts.

Comment: `javac` enforces classname=filename for _public_ class but not for default=package. And while traditionally `java` is given the name of a compiled main class, or a jar or (since j9) module containing such, since j11 `java filename.java` _compiles and runs_ a sourcefile which may contain a class with nonmatching name either public or package; see [12th bullet here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-3B1CE181-CD30-4178-9602-230B800D4FAE__USINGSOURCE-FILEMODETOLAUNCHSINGLE--B5E57618). However this is confusing and (thus) not recommendable.